# Send Mail fails? [php + xampp]

Tags: php, sendmail

In sendmail error log I get this error:

```
13.05.17 22:33:23 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. x41sm21034997eey.17 - gsmtp<EOL>
13.05.17 23:02:55 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. m48sm20850393eeh.16 - gsmtp<EOL>
13.05.17 23:08:05 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. bn53sm21242331eeb.7 - gsmtp<EOL>
13.05.17 23:43:54 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. x41sm21511836eey.17 - gsmtp<EOL>
13.05.18 00:07:17 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. w52sm21617356eev.12 - gsmtp<EOL>
13.05.18 03:03:16 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. e50sm22561955eev.13 - gsmtp<EOL>
13.05.18 20:28:20 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. d10sm3967825wik.0 - gsmtp<EOL>
13.05.19 05:14:31 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. dj7sm5901394wib.6 - gsmtp<EOL>
```

And my sendMail file:

[sendmail]

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=artemkller@gmail.com
auth_password=hidepass
force_sender=artemkller@gmail.com
```

My code:

```
mail
(
    $email,
    'Driptone - Activate your account',
    'Hello '.$username.'. you must activate your account before
    you can start using your account.
    You can activate your account by clicking on the following link:
    http://localhost/drip/activate.php?u='.$this->get['user_id'].'&a='.$this->get['generated_code'].'
    Thank you,
    Driptone.',
    'From: noreply@driptone.com'
);
```

What is wrong with this? It used to work, but now not?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the path to your "sendMail" file.  That way other people who are trying to learn it can benefit more from your question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that gmail uses secure (TLS) servers to prevent spam.

Make sure you PHP installation has SSL support (look for an "openssl" section in the output from `phpinfo()`).

You can set the following settings in your `PHP.ini`:

```
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","587");
```

also you can find your solution [here](http://byitcurious.blogspot.com/2009/04/solving-must-issue-starttls-command.html) if above dosent help you.